# What is the default memory allocation for shell process by linux

Tags: linux, process, memory, limit

What is the default memory allocation for shell process by Linux , i mean is there any upper limit for shell process or any process.

Answer (score 1):

From `man bashbuiltins`:

> `ulimit [-HSTabcdefilmnpqrstuvx [limit]]`
>
> Provides  control  over the resources available to the shell and
>   to processes started by it, on systems that allow such  control.

Use `ulimit -a` to show current limits.

Answer (score 1):

Resource limits are generally controlled through `ulimit` (user-based) or `sysctl` (system-based).

For example, the `kernel.shmmax` parameter, set by `sysctl` defines the maximum size in bytes of a single shared memory segment that a Linux process can allocate in its virtual address space.

`ulimit` is used to set the limits of normal user processes.  These values are usually configured in `/etc/security/limits.conf` as defaults, but can be changed on a per user / per session basis.  They have both hard and soft limits.